# Пожалуйста, помогите понять кусок кода

Tags: python-3.x

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.login('email', 'password')

@client.event
def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello was received!')

@client.event
def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run()
```

Как работают `@client.event` и как называется подобная конструкция?

Comment: Эта конструкция называется "декоратор": https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/. Как она работает в данном случае, надо читать в документации модуля `discord`

Comment: А вот и ссылки на документацию: http://discordpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client.event#discord.Client.event и http://discordpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client.event#event-reference Если коротко - так регистрируюся события для отслеживания, например `on_message`, будет вызван при создании и отправки сообщения на сервер.

Comment: Вот здесь очень подробный ответ: [Unserstanding python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта конструкция называется ***декоратором***.

Действует она следующим образом. Если `@decorator` - некоторый декоратор, то следующая конструкция

```
@decorator
def f(args):
    # . . .
```

будет преобразована в такую:

```
def f(args):
    # . . .

f = decorator(f)
```

То есть, в данном случае декоратор - некоторая функция, преобразующая свой аргумент.

P.S. Декораторы в *Python* - довольно обширная тема. Если хотите разобраться в ней поподробнее, почитайте 38-ю главу книги

> *Лутц М.*
>
> Изучаем Python, 4-е издание. – Пер. с англ. – СПб.: Символ-Плюс, 2011. – 1280 с., ил.
>
> ISBN 978-5-93286-159-2

Comment: тогда почему у нескольких функций один и тот же декоратор, и зачем?

Comment: @alexdless, чтобы одно и то же не писать. Один декоратор сделал и хоть с сотней функций используешь.

Comment: @alexdless: главное понять, что функция является обычным объектом в Питоне, который можно передать как аргумент, вернуть как результат итд. Декоратор это просто функция, которая принимает и возвращает функции (плюс удобный @-синтакс, но декораторы существовали и до введения @-синтаксиса, например, [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)). Тоже самое для декораторов для классов: функция, которая принимает и возвращает классы (класс также является полноценным объектом в Питоне).